# Problem about circuit with capacitor and switch

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis

I'm new to circuits. I would like to calculate the current \$i_x(t)\$ at \$t=0^-\$ of the following circuit:

[image]

I know that the capacitor acts as open circuit when it is in its steady state at \$t=0^-\$, so I represented the circuit as the following (where in yellow I highlighted the flow of current).

[image]
.

My question is why \$v_c(0^-)=\frac{V_S}{3}\$? Also, when the voltage is saturated, should't the voltage across the capacitor be equal to the voltage of the generator? Also why are we doing \$i_x(0^-)=\frac{V_s}{3R_1}\$? I'm surely missing something.

Comment: As you have drawn in yellow the current is \$ I_X  = \frac{V_S}{R_1 + R_1 + R_1} = \frac{V_S}{3 R_1}\$. And because no current is flowing through \$R_2\$ resistor the capacitor voltage will be equal to \$ V_C =  I_X * R_1 = \frac{V_S}{3 R_1}*R1 = \frac{V_S * R_1}{3 R_1}=\frac{V_S}{3}\$

Comment: Thank you very much!